# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setHomeActionContentDescription [int]?

Tags: java, android, reflection, nosuchmethoderror

When I use reflection to get method `setHomeActionContentDescription` like this:

```
Method setHomeActionContentDescription = ActionBar.class.getDeclaredMethod(
    "setHomeActionContentDescription", Integer.TYPE);
```

I get NoSuchMethodException:
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setHomeActionContentDescription [int]`

Comment: What is your sdk build version ?

Comment: @Jivy minSdkVersion 14 targetSdkVersion 21

Comment: Ok, then be careful because the setHomeActionContentDescription method is only available with api 18.
Your code works great with API 18 but will not work with API<18

Comment: @Jivy so, do I have any choice solve 
compatibility with api 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this method is not available before API 18. Even with the use of reflection, the method is not available. If you want use this method, you can use a workaround from SherlockNavigationDrawer library :

```
            try {
                setHomeAsUpIndicator = ActionBar.class.getDeclaredMethod("setHomeAsUpIndicator",
                        Drawable.class);
                setHomeActionContentDescription = ActionBar.class.getDeclaredMethod(
                        "setHomeActionContentDescription", Integer.TYPE);

                // If we got the method we won't need the stuff below.
                return;
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // Oh well. We'll use the other mechanism below instead.
            }

            final View home = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.home);
            if (home == null) {
                // Action bar doesn't have a known configuration, an OEM messed with things.
                return;
            }

            final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) home.getParent();
            final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
            if (childCount != 2) {
                // No idea which one will be the right one, an OEM messed with things.
                return;
            }

            final View first = parent.getChildAt(0);
            final View second = parent.getChildAt(1);
            final View up = first.getId() == android.R.id.home ? second : first;

            if (up instanceof ImageView) {
                // Jackpot! (Probably...)
                upIndicatorView = (ImageView) up;
            }
```

Source: https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/SherlockNavigationDrawer/blob/master/SherlockNavigationDrawer/src/com/sherlock/navigationdrawer/compat/SherlockActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.java#L97

As you can see, if it is not possible to access methods, he try to directly get the ImageView. When you have it, you can directly do a setContentDescription or whatever you want.